# Manifest is invalid chrome error

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I try to install a Chrome extension that I made, it gives the following error -

[image]

My Manifest file code-

```
"browser_action":{
      "default_icon":"icon.png",
      "default_title":"Facebook Troll Chat",
      "popup":"popup.html"
   },
   "description":"Troll Emoticons for Facebook chat!",
   "name":"Facebook Troll Chat",
   "manifest_version":2,
   "version":"10.1"

}
```

I don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
{
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "FacebookTrollChat",
        "popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "description": "TrollEmoticonsforFacebookchat!",
    "name": "FacebookTrollChat",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "10.1"
}
```

it should fix the problem.

For any Manifest Errors use [**`JSONLint`**](http://jsonlint.com/) for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

check your chrome version. if it's not the lasted version. update it.

i tested you manifest, It's ok.